# Swift: Conditional type casting (as?, as!) in if let statements

Tags: swift

What is the recommended approach for using 'as' in combination with 'if' if there are multiple possibilities for the base class, e.g.

```
var delegate:AnyObject?

func myFunction(){

if let delegate = self.delegate as? A1ViewController {
  delegate.callFunction()
}

if let delegate = self.delegate as? A2ViewController{
   delegate.callFunction()
}
}
```

Is there a way to combine the two if statements above?

e.g.

```
if let delegate = self.delegate as? A1ViewController || let delegate = self.delegate = self.delegate as? A2ViewController {
   delegate.callFunction()
}
```

Comment: What type is self.delegate? I think you might be missing the point of delegation here. It shouldn't matter what type the delegate is, just that it implements a certain interface.

Comment: Ok so the delegate could be better defined (rather than AnyObject) but thats not really the question. The question is how to combine to "as" if statements.

Comment: Alessandro's answer below is correct for what you're trying to do. But I do suggest you look into creating a protocol that contains the callFunction method so you don't have to do any casting.

Comment: Alessandro's answer is still not correct.

Comment: Why do the title of this question refers to `guard`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only two options and assure that at least one will not be null, one way to make it a single line would be using ternary operator:

`delegate = self.delegage as? A1ViewController != null ? self.delegage as? A1ViewController : self.delegage as? A2ViewController`

Comment: what is the resulting type of delegate here? This can't compile because the type of delegate needs to be known statically.

Comment: Besides the typos, since `delegate` is declared as `AnyObject?` you won't be able to invoke `callFunction` on it.

Comment: The questions was eddited adding delegates' type. However, by any means delegate would be able to call a method that is not present in its class hierarchy tree, which lets us to infeer that the target method is part of the AnyObject type.

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of the purpose of what you want to achieve (in my opinion there are some issues in your code design if you need this), this is my 2 cents on writing the cleanest code for this kind of checks.

You can't currently OR two `let ... = ...` statements. You could anyway work around that creating a common protocol that includes the common call, extend the classes and use a single code path.

```
protocol CommonDelegateProtocol { 
    func callFunction()
}

extension A1ViewController : CommonDelegateProtocol {}
extension A2ViewController : CommonDelegateProtocol {}

// then...

if let delegate = self.delegate as? CommonDelegateProtocol {
   delegate.callFunction()
}
```

### Version with switch in case of different code paths.

If you instead need different code paths, this is my best bet. In this way you also force your code to evaluate all the possible cases.

```
switch self.delegate {
case let d as A1ViewController:
    // "d" is of type A1ViewController
    d.callA1Function()
case let d as A2ViewController:
    // "d" is of type A2ViewController
    d.callA2Function()
default:
    print("Uncovered case")
}
```

Comment: Yes but this still doesn't answer the question - this introduces redundant code - the question is how to OR two as statements

Comment: I added another possible approach to solve what you want to achieve with less repetitions

Comment: Using a protocol (like described in the first part of this answer) is a pretty good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro's answer above is the closest thing to what you're trying to do. The reason you can't combine these two statements in an if let binding is that you're attempting to bind to two different classes. What type do you expect `delegate` to be inside the if-let block? It could be either `A1ViewController` or `A1ViewController` depending on what the delegate is at runtime. So this can't be compiled because delegate needs a static type at compile time. I suggest you do what Alessandro suggests with the switch statement or create a protocol to abstract both types.

Comment: Yes I thinked about the same approach using a common protocol and I updated my answer  ;)